# Stop activity from scrolling with edit text android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am having a problem where when I am typing in an edit text, when a new line is inserted into the edit text, the entire activity scrolls down. But I would just like the edit text to scroll down so the user could still see the text.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `EditText` in a `NestedScrollView`. Think of the scroll view as like a window into some scrollable content - you can make it a suitable size for your activity and so the user can see enough of the `EditText`, which can grow to whatever size without changing the size of the scroll view it lives in.